Accessing claims from OIDC in Blazor Server
To start, I am a developer and this is my first time working with OIDC and SSO. I did not set up the IDP (PingFederate) side of things, only wrote the code to add it to a web app. The SSO is properly signing in through the IDP.
My trouble is accessing custom claims that should be in the token, like claims loaded through LDS. The specific claim I am trying to access is configured as samAccountName on the IDP side. When I run the debugger to look at the claims, only three claims are present: NameIdentifier, jti, and auth_time.
Here is the code in which I am accessing the claims
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    authState = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    claims = authState.User.Claims.ToList();
    var jtiClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "jti")?.Value;
    var authTimeClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "auth_time")?.Value;
    var nameIdentifier = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

    getRoles();
    setDdsButtonVisiblity();
    handDdsPageAccess();
}

These are the claims within the claims list above. That custom claim, the samAccountName, is not present here.
Picture of claims within debugger
I have also tried mapping the samAccountName claim within the OIDC middleware code, but that results in the same issue.
This is the middleware code below
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var appSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value;

    options.Authority = appSettings.OidcAuthority;
    options.ClientId = appSettings.OidcClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = appSettings.OidcClientSecret;

    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("samAccountName", "samAccountName");
});

I have checked out other posts and resources, but I can't quite figure it out. I would greatly appreciate in advice.

How did you configure the custom claim called "samAccountName" on IDP side?

@FarzadM. Another department set up the IDP side, I only worked on the dev side. I'm trying to contact them about this also, but while I'm waiting for a response from them I turned here. I definitely do think asking them about how the claims were set up are the best option but wanted more insight. All I currently know is from a screenshot of the IDP side, where the custom claims, including samAccountName, are under a section called "Contract Fulfillment." What it looks like is "samAccountName" being mapped to "samAccountName (Authentication Policy Contract)," if that is helpful.

It's crucial to verify whether the issued cookie from IDP contains the claims you need or not. If it does, you should be able to access all user claims through authState.User.Claims, given that you have options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true. No specific ClaimActions is needed. You use ‍‍‍‍ClaimActions when the claim is provided and you want to map it to another claim key.

What Redirect URL did you provide in the IDP?

@ToreNestenius, the redirect URI that I'm currently testing and working with and provided to the IDP for the dev configuration of the web app is https://localhost:7155/signin-oidc. It's just the base link and home page of the web app.

are the claims you expect to see inside the tokens? can you post a sample token? I do have a blog post about troubleshooting claim problems here https://nestenius.se/net/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/
